# Selecting span-like button with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to Selenium and I have been trying to create a scraper to get some information from Brazil's treasury website to then perform some simulations. In order to reveal part of the input boxes on the website (https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/calculadora.htm) it is necessary to select a button that was created as a span ([image here - the arrow is on the right-hand side of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obG3W.png)).

I managed to select the element, but since it is truly a span (and not a button), I couldn't use the `.click()` method, and since the input boxes are hidden, I can't fill them. Does anybody have an idea how to work around this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/calculadora.htm")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/h2/span').click()

Exception has occurred: ElementNotInteractableException
Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to perform `js_click` actions where regular clicks failed. Here's the full script for that:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_base(self):
        self.open("https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/calculadora.htm")
        self.click("div#onetrust-close-btn-container button")
        self.js_click("span.perfil-notice__close")
        self.js_click("h2.td-calc-form__avancedsimu span")
        self.highlight("input#dataVenda")
        self.type("input#dataVenda", "31/12/2022")
        self.highlight("input#taxaPapelVenda")
```

You'll need `seleniumbase`.
Tests are run with `pytest`.

Comment: Thanks. It took me longer to realize than I am proud to admit that I had to run your code using pytest for it to work. However the code runs from top to bottom, skipping all breakpoints. I am using VSCode. Is there a way to run it without pytest (preferably) or to make it stop on breakpoints?

Comment: You can try using ``pytest --final-debug``, which will create a breakpoint at the very end of the test. (It's a relatively new feature.)